# How to set design view Items in UserControl such that multiple sub controls have these items

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a UserControl, it internally has 10 ComboBox'es.

I need to make it so my parent UserControl has a design time Items property, just like ComboBox'es normally have, which will then set all the children ComboBox'es.

The define for the design time of Items for ComboBox'es is:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Gets an object representing the collection of the items contained in this
//     System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.
//
// Returns:
//     A System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection representing the items in
//     the System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.
[MergableProperty(false)]
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ListControlStringCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
[Localizable(true)]
public ComboBox.ObjectCollection Items
{
    get;
}
```

So that would work, except this wouldn't apply the internal Items to the combobox elements.

I can't assign them to multiples since these ComboBox.ObjectCollection Items are linked to specific ComboBox'es when created.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So all of the UserControl's ComboBoxes have the *same* collection?

Comment: That's the goal.

The basic idea is that when i use the parent control i will only have to set the Items collection on the parent usercontrol and it will be propagated down to the children controls as if I had set the Items for each combobox in the designer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `BindingList<string>` to accomplish that:

```
private BindingList<string> items = new BindingList<string>();

public UserControl1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(items, string.Empty);
  comboBox2.DataSource = new BindingSource(items, string.Empty);
}

[MergableProperty(false)]
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ListControlStringCollectionEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
[Localizable(true)]
public BindingList<string> Items {
  get { return items; }
}
```

Comment: Bingo! problem solved. thanks for the help. this solves about 30 issues for me. no joke, no exaggeration.